# How can I retrieve characters from a string after finding them?

Tags: python

I would like to search some characters in a string and then save them in a variable but the way it is written in the string. For example:

```
text = "this is a Long text"
searchinput = "a long"

if searchinput.lower() in text.lower():
    print(searchinput)
```

The output is, of course, "a long", but I want the output to be exactly as in the text variable, that is "a Long".

In short: Check if a string is in a longer string and than retrieve the long string version. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to get the index and then go from there. This is an example to give you an idea.

```
text = "this is a Long text"
check = "a long"

try:
    i = text.lower().index(check.lower())
    print(text[i:i+len(check)])

except:
    print('Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Python example:

```py
import re
regex = r"a long"
test_str = "this is a Long text"
regexMatches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE)
matches = [i.group() for i in regexMatches]
print(matches)
```